# How to execute from select result (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I created table with grants list. How I can execute grants from this table ?
Something like
select * from grants_table;
then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE result from select

Comment: Any chance you can post your grant table and sample data. I'm curious to see your implementation

Answer (score 2):

You could write a loop

```
begin
  for grant in (select * from grants_table)
  loop
    execute immediate grants.column_with_ddl;
  end loop;
end;
```

Most likely, you'll want to do some amount of logging/ exception handling/ etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is of considerable size you could take advantage of the bulk operations and binds, something among the lines:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE cursor_ref IS REF CURSOR;
  c1 cursor_ref;
  TYPE grants_t IS TABLE OF grants%ROWTYPE;
  grants_tab grants_t;
  rows_fetched NUMBER;
  errors  NUMBER;
  dml_errors EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA exception_init(dml_errors, -24345);
BEGIN
  OPEN c1 FOR 'SELECT * FROM grants';
  FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO grants_tab;
  rows_fetched := c1%ROWCOUNT;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of grants: ' || TO_CHAR(rows_fetched));
  BEGIN
    FORALL i IN 1 .. grants_tab.count 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '< some ddl> :1' USING grants_tab(i);
    EXCEPTION WHEN dml_errors THEN
      errors := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of errors is ' || errors);
      FOR j IN 1..errors LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error ' || j || ' occurred on iteration ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(j).ERROR_INDEX);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Oracle error is ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(j).ERROR_CODE));
      END LOOP;
  END;
END;
/
```

Comment: Curious how can the forall handle EXCEPTIONs or errors?

Comment: See the updated answer.